# Weird glare effect

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, lighting, glare

Whenever I attempt to implement glare in this planet scene, it creates odd effects as seen in the image. The black dot is a sphere with an emission material and the strength set to 1000. In front of the dot is a point light with strength set to 1200. I'm trying to make it so that I have glare coming off of the sphere so that it looks like a sun but then this happens.[image]
[image]

Comment: The _Screen_ operation is what is causing your problem -Since you're "Adding" the glare to a (mostly) black background, why not use _Add_ instead?

Comment: Yes, that solved it. For some reason, in the tutorial, no glitches happen when the guy has it on screen but he puts it to add later.